# AWS Cloudwatch API with Powershell

Tags: powershell, api, amazon-cloudwatch

Sorry if this is a naive question but I can't find any examples of authenticating with Cloudwatch API in Powershell. What I'm trying to do is call Cloudwatch API endpoint (which I assume is monitoring.us-east-2.amazonaws.com?) via invoke-restmethod and get some data back.

Any pointers are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There is a powershell module for AWS that includes commands for accessing cloudwatch have you looked at this module? AWSPowershell?

Comment: Thanks, yes I have, but does it give me enough data points to build a graph with? I've done some other APIs that give metric data back in JSON which are pretty detailed.

Comment: Can you point me to some examples on how to run Get-CWMetricData? There's surprising lack of content around examples on this - hard time for a beginner.

I stole a query from grafana and tried to pass to the cmdlet but it doesn't like it. 
Cannot bind parameter 'MetricDataQuery'. Cannot convert the "{queryhere}" value of type "System.String" to type "Amazon.CloudWatch.Model.MetricDataQuery".

Answer (score 0):

Check this Doc out:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/specifying-your-aws-credentials.html

Here is what I think you need to do based on your question:

Add the desired Profile:

```
Set-AWSCredential `
             -AccessKey AKIA0123456787EXAMPLE `
             -SecretKey wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY `
             -StoreAs MyNewProfile
```

I like to start out by setting my credential:

```
Set-AWSCredential -ProfileName MyProfileName
```

You can make things a little easier with a default configuration:

```
Initialize-AWSDefaultConfiguration -ProfileName MyProfileName -Region my-region-0
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Does this work for running the Powershell cmdlets or also call the API endpoint via invoke-restmethod?

The reason I'm trying to do the latter is I have already written a bunch of PoSh scripts working with response JSON that would be easy to tweak here and there.

Comment: Hello, It will work for anything regarding the AWS Tools for Powershell. For the invoke-rest method, you would probably be creating a completely different shell, so I would expect additional credentials would need to be provided. Multiple Profiles can be added to one machine, so add the profile needed for the specific script / action every time for least privileges.

Comment: Hello, If this helped, could you mark it as an answer? It helps me out. Thanks